# How do I find a file path

Tags: r, file, package

I am learning to work with ODEs in R out of atextbook and have these lines of code that I am convinced are the problem

```
#Library of R ODE solvers
library("deSolve")

#ODE routine
setwd("c:/R/bme_ode/chap1")
source("bioreactor_2.R")
```

the path in setwd is out of the textbook where they are keeping there R routines (their words) how do I find where mine are being kept

Comment: `file.choose()` might help you, but I would recommend using projects in Rstudio with all your files within the project

Comment: So if I want to find the folder where the R routine "bioreactor_2.R is being kept I should run file.choose("bioreactor_2.R")

Comment: well to find the path to that folder

Comment: Just run file.choose() and navigate to where your folder is. Copy the output string and use that in future

Comment: So I have tried a few times and my computer keeps saying that bioreactor_2.R doesnt exist so I now think that there is something I was supposed to download but havnt  sorry lol

Comment: Ok I found it online but I dont think I can download the directory can you tell me how? lol thank you again
https://www.lehigh.edu/~wes1/odepde_R/ode_v1/chap1_ode_v1/

Comment: Download it manually (easiest) or use `download.file(link)` with with a link to the appropriate online location. After this simply point `source` to the appropriate file.

Comment: I tried and I got this error
download.file("https://www.lehigh.edu/~wes1/odepde_R/")
Error in download.file("https://www.lehigh.edu/~wes1/odepde_R/") : 
  argument "destfile" is missing, with no default

Comment: I think the problem is because I want to download the whole odepde_R directory instead of just one file but idk